# How to detect IE7 by the user agent string, leaving out newer IE versions running in quirks mode

Tags: javascript, regex, user-agent

I need to detect IE7 (and IE6) using the user agent string:

I have made the following regex:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE [67]\./)
```

However, IE9 in quirks mode also matches the regex with the following [user agent](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/):

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 7.1; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C)
```

I could make two regexes:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE [67]\./) !== null 
  && navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident\/5\.0/) === null
```

Is there a way I can combine them into one?

Comment: First question would of course be: Why do you "need" to detect IE7 by User Agent string? Feature detection should be preferred over browser detection, and then there are always [Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I knew that one would come :P I need to address an issue which is not related to a specific feature. The issue is only applied to native IE7 installations (not in IE7+ in compatibility mode). Finally, I can't use conditional comments, as the solution is distributed as a javascript widget. Thus as far as I can see, using user agent strings is the best option.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question about that specific issue. Is it a rendering issue or a JScript issue? If it's the latter, then JScripts [Conditional Compilation statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kx09ct1(v=vs.80).aspx) may be usefull.

Comment: It is a javascript issue. This is a temporary solution, so I might just go with the double user agent matching. I'll check into the conditional compilation though :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Trident part always comes after the MSIE part, you can use a lookahead:

```
/MSIE [67]\.(?!.*Trident[5]\.0)/
```

I'm not familiar with user agents strings, but I'm guessing that maybe IE10 in quirks mode could have a Trident version > 5, so you could change it to:

```
/MSIE [67]\.(?!.*Trident[1-9])/
```

**UPDATE: second regex  edited to include earlier versions of Trident too, e.g. Trident/4.0 in IE8, as well as potential later versions >= 10.**

UPDATE2: Cleaned up RegEx's to be valid in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting a JavaScript solution made along with the regex....

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
// Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
  var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
    if (re.exec(ua) != null)
      rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
  }
  return rv;
}
function checkVersion()
{
  var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
  var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

  if ( ver > -1 )
  {
    if ( ver >= 8.0 ) 
      msg = "You're using a recent copy of Internet Explorer."
    else
      msg = "You should upgrade your copy of Internet Explorer.";
  }
  alert( msg );
}
```

This solution is actually given my Microsoft, you can refer to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, however, it doesn't solve the problem with IE9 in quirks mode, returning the following user agent string: `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 7.1; Trident/5.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C)`

Comment: Updating this old thread:  The Microsoft link above is obsolete (that is, not yet updated, to reflect Trident change).  The best way as of now January 2014, seems to be this rule: If the lower case converted userAgent contains "msie" or "trident" then the Browser is Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank god browser detects are largely in the past, BUT @Clay Ferguson's suggestion won't work -> IE 11 no longer includes IE in the userAgent: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/21/internet-explorer-11-user-agent-string-ua-string-sniffing-compatibility-with-gecko-webkit.aspx

Comment: @ScottStafford, do you know of an example of an IE userAgent that contains neither "msie" nor "trident"?  If so please share, so we can see how to update code based on your discovery. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a relevant but why not to try `document&&document.documentMode?document.documentMode:variable` where `variable` would be identifier for not being IE at all?